# Importing libraries in JupyterNotebook

Tags: python, installation, geopandas, jupyter-notebook

```
import solaris as sol
from solaris.data import data_dir
import os
import json
```

I already installed solaris:

```
git clone https://github.com/cosmiq/solaris.git
cd solaris
git checkout [branch_name] 
conda env create -f environment-gpu.yml
conda activate solaris
pip install  .
```

Also installed geopandas and ipython in my environment using conda. But still, it is showing

```
import solaris
ModuleNotFoundError                       
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-21f76cd8981d> in <module>
----> 1 import solaris as sol

E:\CSE 499\solaris\solaris\__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from . import bin, data, eval, nets, preproc, raster, tile, utils, vector
      2 
      3 __version__ = "0.4.0"

E:\CSE 499\solaris\solaris\data\__init__.py in <module>
      1 import os
      2 import pandas as pd
----> 3 import geopandas as gpd
      4 import gdal
      5 import rasterio

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geopandas'
```

Comment: I have installed geopandas in the same environment

Comment: Where is the geospatial component of the question ?

Answer (score -1):

run 'cmd' or 'anaconda prompt' as admin if you are working on Windows

then activate the enviroment to install geopandas using:

Run this:

> conda install -c conda-forge geopandas

then activate Jupyter

Run this:

> Jupyter Notebook

inside Jupyter notebook

> import geopandas as gpd